# maven didn't add main-class properly

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, manifest

I want to compile my Java-Project with maven but it didn't add the main-class to the manifest file. So i can't run the jar outside of intellij. I've added the main-class to my pom.xml but it don't show up in the manifest file.

I'm using the build function of intellij on a Win10 machine and maven3 (IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3).

If i run the jar i get the error

```
$java -jar myJar.jar
kein Hauptmanifestattribut, in myJar.jar
```

(German for: *no main manifest attribute, in myJar.jar*, i don't know the exact english translation for that but it means: *no main class specified*)

I've tried serveral maven plugins (maven-compile, maven-jar, maven-shade) and ways to specify the main-class but non of them added it to the manifest file. The only way i get this to work is when i added the line

```
Main-Class: Main
```

by hand.

my pom file (yes, my main-class called *Main* and yes it works fine when i added it by hand)

```
...

    <groupId>com.myname</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

...
```

the manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: dspicuzz
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_65
```

If i added the line by hand it runs fine

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: dspicuzz
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_65
Main-Class: Main
```

But i can't get maven to generate it for me this way.

Comment: How do you generate your .jar file? Do you use `Build > Build Artifacts` or `Maven > ModuleName > jar > jar:jar`? Using the first one I have already encounter your issue.

Comment: What Maven command do you use? I would suggest to use `mvn clean package`.

Comment: What happens when you go to Maven tab -> your_project -> Lifecycle and double-click 'package'? Do you see BUILD SUCCESS and the location of you jar file?

Comment: I use ```Build > ... ```

Comment: I let intellij do it for me, so i cant tell you witch maven command it use

Comment: @egallardo i will try this monday

Comment: @egallardo when i run ```Maven tab -> your_project -> Lifecycle and double-click 'package'``` i get a 'BUILD SUCCESS'
But the manifest has not changed

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using the build function of intellij on a Win10 machine and maven3
>   (IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3).

IntelliJ's build will not regenerate your jar file. Try running the package goal to recreate the jar file.

Verify that your package name matches you directory structure: `com.mytest.Main`

If there is no package it will also work but make sure the directory structure has no package structure either.

This will work:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myname</groupId>
    <artifactId>runnable</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.myname.Hello</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Hello.java

```
package com.myname;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

run:

```
C:\runnable>java -jar target\runnable-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Hello
```

And, this is the generated manifest file by the maven-jar plugin:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: egallardo
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_181
Main-Class: com.myname.Hello
```

Also check that your sources directory is properly marked in intellij (in light blue) This image is for the packageless version.

[image]

These are step by step instructions on how to create the project from scratch using IntelliJ:

- Create New Project
- Choose Maven
- Select your SDK (Java 1.8 or so)
- Leave 'Create from archetype' unchecked
- Click Next
- Group id: com.myapp
- Artifact id: runnable
- Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT (default)
- Click next
- Project name: runnable (default)
- Project Location: C:\code\java\runnable
- Click Finish
- Select 'Enable auto-import' if prompted
- Copy and past the `<build>` and `<properties>` sections to your pom.xml file
- Expand runnable -> src -> main -> java
- right click on java folder and click New -> java class
- Type Main as the new class name and kind: class (default)
- Type psvm and click tab to generate the main method
- Add a print statement: System.out.println("Hello");
- Using the maven tab double click package
- The jar file will be created in C:\code\java\runnable\target\runnable-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- try running it with:

`java -jar C:\code\java\runnable\target\runnable-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Check that the jar file date matches the time when you clicked package.
If the above doesn't work, you might have found a bug. Try a different JDK version.

Comment: I doubt this is the answer. I guess the class is defined without a package.

Comment: It could also be a package mismatch

Comment: But then it should not be working to add the class name by hand.

Comment: @JFMeier This actually adds it to the manifest file: `<mainClass>com.myname.Hello</mainClass>`, I'll add the generated manifest.

Comment: @JFMeier I think you're right, there must be no package name if it runs when adding it manually

Comment: DrDean, it will work with or without the package, I just tried it also without package and maven correctly creates the manifest file

Comment: Intellij autocomplete com.myapp.Main to Main. Also i think egallardo is right. But i will try it Monday when im back at work.

Comment: I also run ```Build > clean``` and ```build > rebuild``` and i deleted the jar file by hand. I can try to build it with maven in the terminal but i dint know if it is configured correctly for this

Comment: I tried the package goal with and without the complete path to my Main-Class but it didn't work. Also the src directory is marked correctly.